# How to change DH Algorithm size when ssl startHandShake on server

Tags: security, ssl, android-6.0-marshmallow, sslhandshakeexception, boringssl

DH Algorithm params is too weak in Android M, like:

```
   if (DH_num_bits(dh) < 1024) {
  OPENSSL_PUT_ERROR(SSL, ssl3_get_server_key_exchange,
                    SSL_R_BAD_DH_P_LENGTH);
  goto err;
}
```

cipher suite has selected `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`  . In java code layer,how to expand the key size when ssl startHandShake to make dh strong?